# Why can't I redeploy Glassfish applications?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-4

We're migrating from a Server 2008R2 box with Glassfish 3 over to a Server 2012R2 box with Glassfish 4.  Everything went swimmingly :-) until I modified one of the applications and attempted to do my first redeploy on the new box.

The Glassfish GUI is throwing this:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Keys cannot be duplicate. Old value of this key property, nullwill be retained. Please see server.log for more details. java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of org/glassfish/web/loader/WebappClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "org/glassfish/web/loader/JdbcLeakPrevention" loader (instance of org/glassfish/web/loader/WebappClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "org/glassfish/web/loader/JdbcLeakPrevention" java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of org/glassfish/web/loader/WebappClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "org/glassfish/web/loader/JdbcLeakPrevention" loader (instance of org/glassfish/web/loader/WebappClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "org/glassfish/web/loader/JdbcLeakPrevention"
```

And server.log contains:

```
[2014-04-02T16:11:13.495-0400] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=289 _ThreadName=admin-listener(29)] [timeMillis: 1396469473495] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Keys cannot be duplicate. Old value of this key property, nullwill be retained
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys cannot be duplicate. Old value of this key property, nullwill be retained
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.WriteableView.setter(WriteableView.java:240)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.WriteableView.invoke(WriteableView.java:150)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.setName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setInitialAppAttributes(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1327)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareAppConfigChanges(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1122)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:486)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]
```

I'm at a loss as I've done similar things lots of times on the old box with no issue.  What might be different with Glassfish 4 that I'd have these problems?  I also note that I'm unable to "undeploy" the application (nothing happens when I try it, acts like it's working, but the app is still there).  I've also tried the "force deploy" option to overwrite the old version of the app, but it fails with the same error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unknown reasons it suddenly started allowing redeploys a week later and has been fine since.  Perhaps a stuck process?  Although, I did restart the glassfish service multiple times.  I was unable to restart the entire server though, as it's part of a 24x7 operation.